# Is it possible to collect all redundant fan-garbage nodes on Lamping's abstract algorithm?

Tags: haskell, optimization, functional-programming, garbage-collection, lambda-calculus

Lamping's abstract algorithm is an efficient way to reduce a class of terms on the pure lambda calculus. I noticed, as asked on [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31599684/is-it-usual-for-interaction-nets-to-leave-piles-of-redundant-fans), that just the abstract algorithm alone leaves piles of redundant nodes after the reduction, which is responsible for an exponential slowdown on the reduction of some terms. Marco Solieri answered by pointing that is common and suggested a technique to amend this problem by converting "safe" fan nodes into flat wires - i.e., garbage-collecting them.

That solution is not perfect, though, as it still leaves many redundant nodes on the final graph. My question is: **is it possible to collect all redundant fan-garbage nodes while executing Lamping's abstract algorithm**?

Comment: Maybe you could add an example where you still have redundant nodes. Also, this may be more appropriate on CS or TCS instead of SO.

Comment: Perhaps TCS is more appropriate.

Comment: Okay. I've posted a question there, in case you're interested... although I find it unlikely I'll get an answer any soon.

Comment: I am interested in this, but I'm not expert enough on this topic to be able to answer.